# Alternative to setting a compound primary key with a nullable column 

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I have a table say `ITEM` that should contain :

```
ID_SERVICE , // foreign key to table SERVICE
ID_FILE , // foreign key to table FILE
ID_FUNCTION  // foreign key to table FUNCTION
```

and it must be identified by those 3 columns (compound primary key) , however my problem is that sometimes i might have an item that doesnt have a function (`ID_FUNCTION` could be null).

How can i redesign this table so that it can handle these constraintes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a unique index not a primary key constraint. A unique index allows for any key to be null, but still enforces uniqueness over every column. The syntax is the same as index but you add unique in front:

```
create unique index i_table_name
    on table_name ( column_names )
       tablespace
       storage ( ... )
       < etc >
```

A unique index will automatically create a unique constraint underlying it. If you don't want the index you could just create the constraint on it's own:

```
alter table table_name
add constraint constraint_name unique (column_names)
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) is more information on the different types of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

is ID_FUNCTION declared as NOT NULL? If it's not nullable, this may be the solution. Alter table so ID_FUNCTION column permits null values.